# Gaming website structure in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, structure, laravel-5

I'm currently migrating my browsergame from my own PHP-MVC framework to the Laravel framework. I'm having some trouble with structuring the site and I don't know what's the best way to do it. How should I structure the homepage and the gameservers?

```
- www.homepage.com (driven by Laravel)
-- /game/s1 (subfolder, so it's driven by the same Laravel instance)
-- /game/s2 (..)
-- /game/s3 (..)
-- ...


- www.homepage.com (driven by Laravel)
- s1.homepage.com (pointing to the homepage Laravel instance)
- s2.homepage.com (..)
- s3.homepage.com (..)
- ...


- www.homepage.com (driven by Laravel)
- s1.homepage.com (driven by a new Laravel instance)
- s2.homepage.com (..)
- ...
```

Well, the third option is possible but ridiculous, as you have to install laravel for each gameserver. So there are two options left.

The first one merges everything together in one domain, but it can be very, very complex.

The second option is an option too, and I see some people using it, but I don't understand why you would do that. Because that same Laravel instance is handling everything. The only difference is that you're pointing to a subdomain instead of a subfolder.

Am I missing something here? Would like to hear your thoughts about it.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel Provides subdomain Routing - therefore there's no need to create subfolder for your "servers" or games.

You can find more information here https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing

Basically you can use this snippet

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{server}.homepage.com'], function () {
  // inline function - should probably be a controller here
  Route::get('game', function ($server) {
    // now you have access to $server which is your s1, s2
  });
});
```

Doing this you will only have to make your subdomains point to your laravel public folder and everything should be working.